# Much difference in time by single user without tool and single user with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to login to an application first with single user and recorded the time using "Page load time" plugin of chrome and then i am trying to login with Jmeter and applying load of Just 1 user but there is much difference in time.
is my approach correct? if yes why there is difference in load time.

Comment: Jmeter is not a browser. You should check similar questions already with answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is Jmeter response time difference between Jmeter run results and manually captured the response time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215150/there-is-jmeter-response-time-difference-between-jmeter-run-results-and-manually)

Answer (score 0):

Well-behaved JMeter request should give the same timings as browser does.

1. Make sure you configure your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to "Retrieve All Embedded Resources"

   [image]

   Ensure that you have `Parallel downloads` ticked
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and configure it to send all the [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) which browser is sending.
3. If web application you're trying to load test is built using [AJAX technology](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) you will need to add the relevant HTTP Request samplers to mimic asynchronous JavaScript-driven calls as JMeter doesn't execute client-side JavaScript. Once done you can combine requests into one "Login" sequence using [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller).

See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for more hints on how to properly configure JMeter for web applications testing.

Comment: But values given by Jmeter is more and by browser is very less